# custom nav bar buttons that use system icons, or image icons

Tags: iphone, ios, button

i'm trying to figure out how to make custom nav bar buttons that use system icons, or image icons.  i followed the tutorial below on how to set a custom nav bar background, and create custom text buttons, and now i'd like to create buttons like the ones in the tutorial but w/ icons instead of text.

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/13/wooduinavigation/

does anyone know how to create custom nav bar buttons with icons?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial is making a UIBarButtonItem object using initWithCustomView:. Basically you can use this to make a button with a custom image. All you have to do is just to create a view with the custom view and pass it as the argument of initWithCustomView:.

Or, more easily, create a UIImage object containing your custom image, and create a UIBarButtonItem object using initWithImage:target:action instead, for example,

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: yourImage
                                                                target: self
                                                                action: @selector(buttonPressed) ];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  newBarButton;
[newBarButton release];
```

Comment: i'm having difficulties setting up a view that uses icons instead of text.  can you help me setup a custom view for icons? thanks!